# Does Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange protocol lower Off-The-Record protocol (OTR) security level?

Tags: authentication, man-in-the-middle, key-exchange, instant-messaging

[Off-the-Record protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) employes [Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (DH). DH protocol does not provide authentication of the communicating parties and, according to many sources, is vulnerable to Man-in-The-Middle (MiTM) attack.

How does it affect the security level of OTR protocol? Is OTR actually does not provide any authentication during the key exchange phase?

And more general question, rather to discuss the topis: why OTR is not employ key exchange protocol with authentication?

Thanks for your answers!

Regards,
B

Comment: OTR includes authentication. I don't remember the details, but I think it signs the DH public key with a long term key.

Comment: Diffie-Hellman is just a function to compute a shared key, not a full protocol. To actually use it, you need to design a protocol on top of it. You can use ephemeral keys without authentication, or any kind of authentication you like.

Comment: Every time Alice encrypts a file, Bob kills a kitten on the internet.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - it seems to be very safe solution, so I would suppose it has authentication for sure. But I am not sure, that is why I asked. According to you second comment: DF is both key-compute algorithm and key-exchange protocol. Wikipedia link in my question navigates to protocol (not algorithm) description.

Comment: @cengizUzun - yeah, true. That's what my last client told me when I asked whether they use encryption. Apparently they like kittens :)